# Как получить нужные элементы из большого словаря?

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции, словарь

Приходит информация от сервера в таком виде:

```
{
    'date': 1539251604,
    'from_id': 511076166,
    'id': 13135,
    'out': 1,
    'peer_id': 2000000007,
    'text': '',
    'conversation_message_id': 6231,
    'fwd_messages': [],
    'important': False,
    'random_id': 521048654,
    'attachments': [
        {
            'type': 'photo',
            'photo': {
                'id': 456239156,
                'album_id': -3,
                'owner_id': 511076166,
                'sizes': [
                    {
                        'type': 's',
                        'url': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fed3/WokhTUD_2Mc.jpg',
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'm',
                        'url': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fed4/5Gqb9dlJIOE.jpg',
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'x',
                        'url': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fed5/nxejisifcP8.jpg',
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'o',
                        'url': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fed6/WKu01Esn_s0.jpg',
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'p',
                        'url': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fed7/Ts8l1jwE7ys.jpg',
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'q',
                        'url': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fed8/WlxWkF4gdl4.jpg',
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'r',
                        'url': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fed9/1PI5cwmKqr4.jpg',
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    }
                ],
                'text': '',
                'date': 1539251598,
                'access_key': 'af125b9950b452218a'
            }
        },
        {
            'type': 'photo',
            'photo': {
                'id': 456239157,
                'album_id': -3,
                'owner_id': 511076166,
                'sizes': [
                    {
                        'type': 's',
                        'url': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1feda/Kkx3EKlIoqs.jpg',
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'm',
                        'url': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fedb/JrzeNLaY0nQ.jpg',
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'x',
                        'url': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fedc/sn2sNSL-ajo.jpg',
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'o',
                        'url': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fedd/mt1Rj3RPDCo.jpg',
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'p',
                        'url': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fede/2cViz9gNm7c.jpg',
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'q',
                        'url': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fedf/n0VGo-Askwk.jpg',
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'r',
                        'url': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fee0/f6UwVoiPYls.jpg',
                        'width': 1,
                        'height': 1
                    }
                ],
                'text': '',
                'date': 1539251602,
                'access_key': 'ea1302d738f5092d1c'
            }
        }
    ],
    'is_hidden': False
}
```

Мне нужно получить из этого всего текста все ссылки, которые идут после 'type': 'r', 'url': (тут их 2). Вопрос, как это реализовать?

Comment: В коде не хватает закрывающих элементов.

Comment: Поправил. Теперь вроде бы всё есть.

Comment: `for x in словарь['attachments']` и внутри `for size in x['sizes']` плюс мелкие дополнительные проверки

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку KeyError: 'sizes'

Comment: Опечатался, `x['photo']['sizes']`. Хотя вы должны это всё сами понимать, если прочитали хотя бы один учебник по питону

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это без проверок, а так, наверное, понадобится их делать:

```
rs = {
    'date': 1539251604,
    'from_id': 511076166,
    ...
}

for attachment in rs['attachments']:
    for img in attachment['photo']['sizes']:
        if img['type'] != 'r':
            continue

        print(img['url'])
```

Консоль:

```
https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fed9/1PI5cwmKqr4.jpg
https://pp.userapi.com/c851016/v851016735/1fee0/f6UwVoiPYls.jpg
```

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо за поправку :)

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает.

Comment: @user311842, тогда отметьте ответ принятым :)